# How to find nearest even number for given int? (given 11 return 12)

Tags: c++, c, int

So how to create a function to return nearest up so nearest to 9 9+ 1 to given int leaving no remainder when divided by 2 int?

Comment: This problem is not uniquely specified.  10 is as close to 11 as 12 is.  Which one do you want?  And what about negative numbers?  And is the input integral or floating point?

Comment: @David: The input is clearly integral, but +1 for the rest of your comment

Comment: I can't believe there are all the up-voted answers to a question that has no answer!

Comment: @David: it's not a great sentence, but I think "nearest up" and "nearest to 9 [is] 9+1" both indicate rounding *up*, and nothing contradicts this by suggesting rounding *down*.

Comment: What if the input is 6? Should the return value be 6 or 8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Nearest" is ambiguous when given an integer. Take, say, 9: both 8 and 10 are even, and are equally near to it. If you want to always go up, then something like...

```
int nearestEvenInt(int to)
{
  return (to % 2 == 0) ? to : (to + 1);
}
```

Comment: Before writing this code, you should say: "I believe that optimizer of my compiler will remove division and branching"

Comment: @Abyx: which division? Which branching? I see only a bitmask and a conditional move, even before optimization.

Answer (score 42):

To round to the nearest int:

```
number+=(number & 1)
```

Comment: You assume that the OP wants to round towards positive infinity. Is this true for negative numbers? or should negative numbers round towards negative infinity?

Comment: For negative values doesn't this give different results according to the sign representation?

Comment: @Jens: It does the same thing for both Sign-Magnitude and Twos Complement, but fails for Ones' Complement (where it turns negative even numbers into odd numbers).

Comment: Change it to `number += (int)((unsigned)number & 1)` and it's 100% portable and correct.

Comment: The answer is not exhaustive. It's rounding up, but the OP didn't ask specifically for up or down. Though the answer is correct for rounding up, there is a much more readable solution given by Abyx.

Answer (score 38):

Round down to even

```
x & ~1
```

Round up to even

```
(x + 1) & ~1
```

Comment: (Note: Unlike most of the answers here, this rounds down instead of up)

Comment: Clear, efficient, concise and exhaustive. This is definitely the best answer as the OP didn't specified up or down.

Comment: round down to even in bash: echo $((x & ~1))

Answer (score 11):

`number % 2 == 0?number:number+1`

Another way is `(number>>1)<<1` <del>but I'm not sure about negatives/little/big-endians.</del>

Comment: `(number>>1)<<1` has UB for negative values. (`>>` is only implementation-defined, but `<<` is undefined; it's a signed arithmetic overflow)

Answer (score 8):

The way I'd normally prefer is `(number+1) & ~1`, *but* not everyone recognises the idiom, so you might have to consider your audience.

In particular, if it's supposed to work for negative integers then non-two's-complement implementations of C and C++ don't recognise the idiom (it'll round odd negative numbers down instead of up on negative sign+magnitude numbers, and turn negative even numbers odd on ones' complement), so it's not entirely portable in the case where negative input is allowed.

The portable answer is `(number % 2 == 0) ? number : number+1;`, and let the compiler worry about optimization.

Beware also that you haven't defined what the result should be for `INT_MAX`, which is odd but for which there does not exist a larger even `int` value.

Comment: Another "portable" possibility is `number + (number % 2)`, which in C99 will round positives towards positive infinity and negative infinity.

Comment: If you want to round away from 0, caf's answer is best. But if you want to round up, you'll need to use `&` or some nasty conditionals.

Answer (score 4):

`if (x %2 == 0) return x; else return x+1;` ?

Answer (score 3):

Since most of the answers here are either nonportable or have excess conditionals, here is the fast and portable answer:

```
number += (int)((unsigned)number & 1)
```

The case to `unsigned` ensures that bitwise-and is defined as expected, and the cast back to `int` (which is well-defined because both possible values of the bitwise and operation, zero or one, fit in `int`) prevents `number` from getting promoted to `unsigned`, which would then result in implementation-defined behavior when it's converted back to `int` to assign the result to `number`.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party, but this is a clean solution

```
n += (n % 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP asked for int, but here's one answer for floats too:

```
number = Math.round(number * 0.5f) * 2; //Closest (up for middle)
number = Math.ceil(number * 0.5f) * 2; //Always Up
number = Math.floor(number * 0.5f) * 2; //Always Down
```